# How to use oracle sys_sxtract_utc like function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have an oracle query that uses `sys_sxtract_utc`  function in where clause:

```
 select * from my_table where sys_sxtract_utc(timestmp) > sys_sxtract_utc(last_stable_date)
```

But I could not use this in postgresql query. I could not find any function like this.
How can I use in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use at time zone in your query to get the current GMT timestamp

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

[PostgreSQL Community Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)